# Reading data from XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have to read the ordertext ("This is an example text") from this XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<order id="">
  <users>
    <user id="123456" nick="nick" done="false" />
  </users>
  <machines>
    <machine id="1234" sd="1234" ref="" done="false" />
  </machines>
  <todos />
  <ordertexts>
    <ordertext>This is an example text </ordertext>
  </ordertexts>
</order>
```

My C# Code looks like this:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(file);
XmlElement node = (XmlElement)xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/order/ordertexts/ordertext");
```

When I write the selected data in another XML File it looks like this:

```
<order>
  <oldOrderText>System.Xml.XmlElement</oldOrderText>
</order>
```

What did I do wrong? Is the XPath incorrect?

I am a C# newbie so I really need every help I can get!

Thanks in advance, geibi

Comment: Please can you show the code you use to write the data.

Comment: I have tested your xpath [here](https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester) and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [XmlElement.InnerText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement.innertext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlElement_InnerText).

When you get the node using this:

```
XmlElement node = (XmlElement)xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/order/ordertexts/ordertext");
```

You still need to use this:

```
string neededText = node.InnerText;
```

to get the value of that node.

Suppose that you're writing the results in a console application. If you try to write the `node` variable, this way:

```
Console.WriteLine(node);
```

Since `node` is not a string, and it's an `XmlElement` object, the [`ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) method of `XmlElement` is going to be called, which returns the object name, hence your new XML had the result as `System.Xml.XmlElement` and not the desired text.